# Upload files in chunks - .Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, http-post

Need help on uploading a file in chunks in .Net core. 
I got a stream of 1GB data, need to split in 64MB chucks and post to an API.

I got the below implementation of posting stream of data in single POST request, need suggestion on splitting the stream and POST in multiple API call

```
private async Task<string> Publish(string siteId, string datasourceName, string projectId, SkyConnection connectionInfo, MemoryStream file, string fileName)
    {
        _authInfo = await GetAccessToken(siteId);
        var datasourceId = string.Empty;
        var boundaryId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        using (var multipartcontent = new MultipartContent("mixed", boundaryId))
        {
            var stringContent = new StringContent(GetPublishRequest(datasourceName, projectId, connectionInfo));
            stringContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            stringContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Disposition");
            stringContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Disposition", "name=\"request_payload\"");
            stringContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            multipartcontent.Add(stringContent);

            file.Position = 0;
            var streamContent = new StreamContent(file);
            streamContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Disposition", $"name=\"tableau_datasource\"; filename=\"{fileName}\"");
            streamContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            multipartcontent.Add(streamContent);

            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, GetUrl($"sites/{_authInfo.SiteId}/datasources?datasourceType=tdsx"));
            req.Content = multipartcontent;
            req.Headers.Add("X-Tableau-Auth", _authInfo.Token);
            req.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var res = await _httpHandler.SendAsync(req);

            res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var joResponse = JObject.Parse(await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            datasourceId = joResponse["datasource"]["id"].ToString();
        }

        return datasourceId;
    }
```